# SSRS reports display data in different sections of report based on conditions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Hi for my ssrs Report I require to have three different sections on my report.
And I would like to split the data in the report based on some conditions.
For example 
Report will contain three sections:
Section A- to display attendee
Section b - to display staff
Section c - to display guest speakers

In my data I have a list of event attendees with the names and definition if they are speaker or attendee or staff under one column.
How could I in ssrs use conditions to display where the names will be displayed. So that they get displayed in the right section. So that attendees get displayed in section a , staff get displayed under section b and so on and so on.

Thanks

Comment: This is a pretty broad question as written.  You're more likely to get quality answers if you post a screenshot of the report design with a question about the exact step(s) you are stuck on.  There are several approaches to filtering data, so the specifics of your situation would be especially useful here.

Comment: ...that being said, in general I would recommend using the Filter option in the setup screen if your "sections" are each a tablix: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633648.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 tablixes, one for each section you want to display.  Use the same dataset for all three tablixes.  In the tablix properties, add a filter to only show the matches for that tablix.

One positive of this approach is that SSRS will only retrieve the dataset once, and will re-use the same data cache for all the tablixes.